# Capacitor Geolocation.getCurrentPosition taking 10seconds to get location in IOS Device

Tags: android, ios, capacitor

While using the application in iPhone I need to use co-ordinates of the device in my application. i am using `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` from Capacitor Plugin. but when I am requesting for GPS Location every time it's taking 10seconds to get co-ordinates. is there a way to increase performance in getting GPS location in both IOS and Android?.
The current version of Capacitor is 2.4.4

Thanks.

Comment: happens to me too! Would love to see a solution to this problem